# Wrong Proof: Infinite cartesian product of countable sets is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We know that if we have two sets $A,B$, $A \times B$ is countable. So basically, the cartesian product of two sets is countable. Then, we know $(A \times B) \times C$ is countable, which means $((A \times B) \times C) \times D$ is countable, and so on and so forth for infinity. Why does this fail?

Comment: By doing this you can inductively prove that any finite product of countable sets is countable however you never actually consider a countable (or uncountable) cartesian product of countable sets.

Comment: The product $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \cdots $ is basically the binary representation of the numbers on $[0,1]$ which is uncountable.

Comment: Ahem... Which of these sets are countable? It is obviously not true that the product of *any* two sets is countable.

Comment: "and so on and so forth for infinity" is hiding all the important details

Comment: Showing something is true for all finite values of, say $n$, does not mean it is true for an infinite number.

Comment: Here's a similar "proof": $0.3$ has a finite decimal expansion. So does $0.33$, and so forth till infinity. Thus, $1/3=0.\overline{3}$ has a finite decimal expansion.

Comment: Induction proves that a set of statements $S(n)$ hold for many, individual, finite $n$.  It does not say it holds for $n=\infty$, whatever that means.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\{0\}$ is a finite set 
$\{0,1\}$ is a finite set
$\{0,1,2\}$ is finite set
 $
\vdots$

Repeating to infinity gives us that the set of all naturals is a finite set(!)

All you can prove using induction is that the Cartesian product of a *finite* number of countable sets is countable.

Comment: This is a good example to keep in mind.